# Sending message to telegram bot, error: {'ok': False, 'error_code': 400, 'description': 'Bad Request: chat not found'}

Tags: python-3.x, bots, telegram-bot

```
import requests

def telegram_bot_sendtext(bot_message):
    bot_token = '101XXXXXX:AAF50Nh75K0jf0cKN16SFpTqge2gijqMsAUV'
    bot_chatID = 'XXXXXXXX'
    send_text = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + bot_chatID + '&parse_mode=Markdown&text=' + bot_message

    response = requests.get(send_text)

    return response.json()


test = telegram_bot_sendtext("Testing Telegram bot")
print(test)
```

I do not understand why this would not work, when I use my bot token in my web browser to getUpdates it works perfectly well. Immediately I try to send a message to the same bot with the same credentials plus my chat_id I get that error.

Comment: The code is fine, this should work. Are you sure the Bot has an existing chat with the user you are trying to send the message to ?